# When can you use "if" in a sentence and it not be conditional?

Tags: conditionals

I'm a little intimidated asking this on this website, being an engineer, but I've wondered this often the past few months so I wanted to ask.  It seems that whenever "if" is used, then it almost always turns the sentence into a conditional.  Sometimes "then" is directly stated, other times it is implied.  When can you use if and it not be conditional?  While listening to a book on tape, I heard something like "Another benefit is that you will make forward progress, if languid."  Here, if seemed to mean "despite being".  Any other examples you can think of?

Comment: There exists what some call a "pseudo conditional": *If you're thirsty, [then] there's beer in the fridge.* Of course there's beer in the fridge whether you're thirsty or not.

Comment: "If" also occurs commonly as a subordinator in **interrogatives**, e.g. "He asked me if I was going to the concert" / "I wonder if he has read my report yet".

Comment: This is an interesting question because of the fundamentally conditional nature of the word “if”. To all voters: consider keeping it open.

Comment: I assumed from the question that the OP is familiar with the various ways *if* is used when a condition is involved and was interested in these other uses. Yes, *if* can be used as in *If you're thirsty...* (I'm supposing/offering -- I don't know) and also *If/given that you're thirsty (you've made it clear)..*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *if* has other uses/meanings:

**if** (conjunction)

> WHETHER
> *Asked if the mail had come
>
> I doubt if I'll pass the course*
>
> Even though : although perhaps
> *An interesting if untenable argument*
>
> And perhaps not even
> *Few if any changes are expected*
> — Often used with not
> *Difficult if not impossible*
>
> If anything
> On the contrary even : perhaps even
> *If anything, you ought to apologize* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if)

*If* can also be a noun, as in *There are no ifs, ands, or buts about it!*

Comment: It might be useful to point out that your first two examples are interrogatives.

Comment: *He didn't know if the mail had come*, for example, isn't a question; nor is *I don't know if I'll pass the course*.

Comment: "If the mail had come" and "if I'll pass the course" are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions).

Comment: Why? The fact is that those "if" expressions are interrogatives, as I said. Do you disagree?

Comment: The first has a sort of embedded question  by virtue of the *if*, but there is no question mark at the end. The sentence itself isn't an interrogative.  *I doubt if I'll pass the course* IMO isn't an embedded question. You could say I'm "questioning" myself, but it's not much different from *I doubt that I'll pass the course.*

Comment: The first doesn't have a 'sort of' embedded question, but a bona fide one. Subordinate interrogative clauses don't, of course, have question marks at the end . We're not talking about the whole sentence, but just the _if_ expressions -- I thought that was obvious.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the first. We can disagree about the second.

Comment: The second is a 'dubitative', a sub-type of subordinate interrogative. From a semantic point of view, it is arguable that the interrogative clause does not express a question at all but simply a proposition, and hence is equivalent to a declarative. Syntactically, though, it can only be an interrogative.